# Amplify: Avoid recursive generated queries when using @hasMany and @belongsTo

Tags: aws-amplify

Consider the below (simplified) schema:

```
type Member @model {
 username: String!
 friends: [Friend!] @hasMany(indexName: "byMemberId")
}

type Friend @model {
  memberID: ID! @index(name: "byMemberId")
  friendID: ID! @index(name: "byFriendId")
  friend: Member! @belongsTo(fields: ["friendID"])
  friendsSince: AWSDateTime!
}
```

This works and does compile, however when running the amplify codegen, the generated typescript queries in `queries.ts` will have recursive queries going back and forth between `Friend` and `Member` until the maxDepth is reached. This is of course not something we want, and I would rather not have to manually edit the queries to not be recursive every time we run the amplify codegen.

Should we consider a different model structure and avoid using @hasMany and @belongsTo all-together, or is there a way of avoiding the recursive queries that are generated?